# Sql server 2008 cache Memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to validate the performance issues in my project I found some thing tricky

```
DECLARE @T DATETIME2 

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
SET @T =GETDATE()
SELECT SUM(cost)
from tblLog
WHERE logID <=100000
PRINT cast(DATEDIFF(ms,@T,GETDATE()) as NVARCHAR(255))+' Milli seconds'


DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
SET @T =GETDATE()
SELECT SUM(cost)
from tblLog
WHERE logID <=100000
PRINT cast(DATEDIFF(ms,@T,GETDATE()) as NVARCHAR(255))+' Milli seconds'
```

When I am executing above code whole at once (same query twice) even though I am cleaning buffer pool memory always second execution is taking lesser time when compared with first could please explain what is missing in this case.

Sample output:

```
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
403 Milli seconds
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
103 Milli seconds
```

Comment: Try adding checkpoint https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1360/clearing-cache-for-sql-server-performance-testing/

Comment: You simply *can't* get millisecond precision from `GETDATE()`. If you want to get statistics use `SET STATISTICS`, eg `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`. `SET STATISTICS IO,XML ON` is far more useful as it returns the IO statistics and actual execution plan. Performance and scalability are primarily affected by IO

Comment: Thak you Joe, I tried including checkpoint I end up in getting same result.